# HTMLで作成した200×200pxの枠をクリックされた時に回転させたい。

Tags: html, css

200×200のHTMLで作成した枠をクリックしたときに回転させたいと思っていますがまったく見当が付きません。
イメージ的には、ある写真が並べられているとします。その写真が200×200pxの大きさです。
ユーザはその写真をクリックすると、Z軸とX軸の方向に回転してその写真に関係するタグを入力できるフォームを作成したいと思っています。

Z軸とX軸というととてもわかりにくいですが、写真をクリックすると写真の裏側(反対側)が見れるようになります。その時のアニメーションが回転ドアのような回り方にしたいのですが可能なのでしょうか？？？

Comment: **Z軸とX軸の方向に回転** のイメージをGIFアニメなどで作成できませんか? **回転ドアのような回り方** と言われると、Y軸による3D回転ではないかと推測できるため、齟齬が生じています。まずはその齟齬を解消するために、思い描いているアニメーションのラフイメージを、わかりやすい形で共有していただくのが良いでしょう。

Answer (score 2):

こういう動作でしょうか。クリックすると画像が回転します。
FirefoxとChrome、IE、Operaで動いているのが確認できましたが、
Chrome/Operaだと連続して回転させるとちょっと挙動が怪しいです。

```js
var pic = document.getElementById("pic");
pic.addEventListener("click", function(){
 pic.classList.toggle("flipped");
});
```

```css
img {
    transition: 0.8s transform ease;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

img.flipped {
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<img id="pic" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/df/Fox_study_6.jpg/399px-Fox_study_6.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

画像の回転の仕方は、以下ページの「SAMPLE 005: toggle」のようなイメージでしょうか。
jQuery CSS3 transitionアニメーション デモ2 | POPS-BLOG-DEMO-020b
http://pops-web.com/main/html/demo-020b.html

jquery.transitというプラグインを用いているようです。
Transit - CSS transitions and transformations for jQuery
http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/